# Is there any way to filter instagram new basic display api by hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to get latest images from instagram account and I am using this url
[https://graph.instagram.com/me/media/?fields=id,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,permalink,caption&access_token={account-token}](https://graph.instagram.com/me/media/?fields=id,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,permalink,caption&access_token=%7Baccount-token%7D) and it get all posts in my instgram account.

Is there any way to get only posts with specific hashtag?

Answer (score 0):

Not right now, Hashtag Search API is only available as part of Instagram Graph API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag-search/